# 特定のキーが押されたら動画を一時停止、再生したい

Tags: javascript, html, 動画

特定のキーが押されたらビデオを一時停止、再生させたいのですがどうすればできるでしょうか。
下記のコードはそれぞれkeydownのサンプルコード
https://www.ipentec.com/document/javascript-accept-keydown
と、videoのサンプルコード
http://www.htmq.com/video/
を参照し自分なりに合わせたものです。
それぞれ単体での動作は確認しております。
間違っている箇所があればご指摘いただきたいです。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id ="movie">
<video src="video play test.mp4" controls loop></video>
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    
 document.onkeydown = keydown;
function keydown() 
  {
       var v = document.getElementById("movie"); 
    

       if (event.shiftKey == true){
            v.play();
      }
        else {
            v.pause();
      }
  }
</script>
```

ご教授よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんな感じでどうでしょうか。
キーが押されたら動画の一時停止・再生をトグルさせたいと理解したので、コードを少し書き換えています。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id ="movie">
<video id="player" src="video play test.mp4" controls loop></video>
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    
 document.onkeydown = keydown;
function keydown(key){
    var v = document.getElementById("player"); 

    if (key.keyCode == 16){
        if (v.paused == true){
            v.play();
        }else{
            v.pause();
        }
    }
}
</script>
```